# How to colorize curves intersection in a manipulate function

Tags: plotting, manipulate, color, visualization, version-7

I need to show the intersection area of two curves, using the **manipulate** function in Mathematica.  Here's a fully working example, and a preview below it :

```
EffPot[r_, Energy_, AngMom_] := -Energy/r + (AngMom^2 - 1)/(2 r^2)

PotCurve[Energy_, AngMom_] := Plot[EffPot[r, Energy, AngMom], {r, 0, 10},
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotPoints -> Automatic,
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, RGBColor[0.60, 0.20, 0.40]}]

TotEnergy[Energy_] := Plot[(Energy^2 - 1)/2, {r, 0, 10},
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, RGBColor[0.20, 0.20, 0.80]}]

Manipulate[Show[PotCurve[Energy, AngMom], TotEnergy[Energy],
    PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-2, 2}},
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    Frame -> True,
    Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
    AxesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.7],
    Ticks -> True,
    GridLines -> Automatic,
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[LightGray, Dashed],
    FrameLabel -> {
            Style["m r / k", 16, Italic],
            Style[Subscript["\[Phi]", "eff"], 16]
    },
    ImageSize -> 500],
    {{Energy, 1, "E"}, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5], 0.01, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}},
    {{AngMom, 0, "J"}, 0.0, 5, 0.01, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}}
    ]
```

Preview (with the intersection area added by hand) :

[image: Two curves intersecting]

So my question is how to colorize the intersection area between both curves ?
Please, take note that I'm using **Mathematica 7**.

Comment: With *Mathematica* 10.2 (Windows) I just get a horizontal line for most of the possible settings of `E` and `J`.  However, you should look at the `Filling` option for `Plot`.

Comment: Please, can you tell me what is wrong with the code, if it isn't working with your version of **Mathematica** ?  The blue curve is just an horizontal line (total energy).  The reddish curve is a potential curve (not a straight line).

Comment: @BobHanlon 's answer shows the fix.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: added use of [PlotLegends package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/PlotLegends/guide/PlotLegendsPackage.html)

Use a single [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) with the option [`Filling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html)

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"];

EffPot[r_, Energy_, AngMom_] :=
 -Energy/r + (AngMom^2 - 1)/(2 r^2)

Manipulate[
 Plot[{
   EffPot[r, Energy, AngMom],
   (Energy^2 - 1)/2},
  {r, 0, 10},
  PlotStyle -> {
    {Thick, RGBColor[0.60, 0.20, 0.40]},
    {Thick, RGBColor[0.20, 0.20, 0.80]}},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-2, 2}},
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  Frame -> True,
  Axes -> True,
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  AxesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.7],
  Ticks -> True,
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[LightGray, Dashed],
  FrameLabel -> {
    Style["m r / k", 16, Italic],
    Style[Subscript["\[Phi]", "eff"], 16]},
  ImageSize -> 500,
  Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, {White, LightGreen}}},
  PlotLegend -> {"EffPot", "TotEnergy"},
  LegendSize -> {.4, .2},
  LegendShadow -> False],
 {{Energy, 1, "E"}, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5], 0.01,
  Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}},
 {{AngMom, 0, "J"}, 0.0, 5, 0.01,
  Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}}]
```

[image]

Manually draw the legend to avoid the slow down in `Manipulate`

```
legend = Row[{
    Graphics[{Thick,
      RGBColor[0.60, 0.20, 0.40],
      Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}],
    " EffPot    ",
    Graphics[{Thick,
      RGBColor[0.20, 0.20, 0.80],
      Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}],
    " TotEnergy"},
   ImageSize -> {200, 20}];

Manipulate[
 Column[{
   legend,
   Plot[{
     EffPot[r, Energy, AngMom],
     (Energy^2 - 1)/2},
    {r, 0, 10},
    PlotStyle -> {
      {Thick, RGBColor[0.60, 0.20, 0.40]},
      {Thick, RGBColor[0.20, 0.20, 0.80]}},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-2, 2}},
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    Frame -> True,
    Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
    AxesStyle -> GrayLevel[0.7],
    Ticks -> True,
    GridLines -> Automatic,
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[LightGray, Dashed],
    FrameLabel -> {
      Style["m r / k", 16, Italic],
      Style[Subscript["\[Phi]", "eff"], 16]},
    ImageSize -> 500,
    Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, {White, LightGreen}}}]},
  Alignment -> Center],
 {{Energy, 1, "E"}, -Sqrt[5], Sqrt[5], 0.01,
  Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}},
 {{AngMom, 0, "J"}, 0.0, 5, 0.01,
  Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: **PlotLegends** isn't working.  Is it compatible with **Mathematica 7** (as stated in the question) ?

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear enough, but the intersection shouldn't include the part going to infinity, below the curves.  It should colorize the finite part only.

Comment: It is unclear what filling you want. See documentation for [Filling](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html) to adjust however you want.

Comment: The legend package works, but the manipulate is now extremely slow and laggy.  I much prefer the legend you have done at first, but apparently this isn't compatible with **Mathematica 7**  :-(